# Graphics Draw-Ordering using ArrayList sorting

Tags: java, performance, sorting, graphics, arraylist

There are similar questions to this, but they're asking *how* this is done. I know how, but I want to know why it doesn't work in the case I'm about to mention.

I've been trying to tweak an engine for a 2D game--sort of along the lines of Legend of Zelda. It has levels, tiles, entities (this may sound familiar) and everything I've implemented with it has worked great so far. I created an entity called Wanderer that, predictably, wanders around the level. When first making the class, I became annoyed with how it always drew over my player character regardless of my position. So I thought a simple fix would be to just continually sort the Level class's "entities" ArrayList based on each entity's y position.

```
 public void tick(){
    Collections.sort(entities, new DrawComp());
    for(Entity e : entities){
        e.tick();
    }
    for(Tile t : Tile.tiles){
        if(t == null) break;
        t.tick();
    }
}
class DrawComp implements Comparator<Entity>{

    public int compare(Entity e1, Entity e2){
        if(e1.y < e2.y) return -1;
        else if(e1.y == e2.y){
            if(e1.x < e2.x) return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It worked great. I had a few Wanderers on screen and if I walked behind one my player would draw behind it, and if I walked in front of one my player would draw in front of it. The problem happens when I add more Wanderers. The whole thing breaks down. When I display the entities' indexes above them, I see 17's above 37's and 36's above 22's. It works for some, and not for others.

So here's what I want to know: Why won't the ArrayList sort function always work properly? Is sorting a larger ArrayList at a faster rate something that takes too much resources?

---

Answer (score 2):

In the compare code, why are you only returning -1 or 0?  if e1.y > e2.y you should return 1, something like this:

```
    if(e1.y < e2.y) return -1;
    else if(e1.y == e2.y){
        if(e1.x < e2.x) {
            return -1;
        } else if (e1.x > e2.x) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
```

Comment: Oh. I guess I followed the online tutorial on sorting I found incorrectly ^.^ 
An example code I found showed return statements either being -1 if an integer (in that case, salary) was less, or 0 if it was not less. Anyway, this fixed it!